# How to show most viewed pages for current logged in user?

Tags: 2013, search, publishing-page, enterprise-search, site-usage

I have one requirement in which I have to show most viewed pages by current logged in user in descending manner.

I have checked using SharePoint 2013 search query as suggested in below link.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/27069.sharepoint-2013-showing-page-views-within-a-sharepoint-page.aspx

But still I am not able to get count for specific user.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks